# Unothorized to create Kubernetes cluser on AWS using kops

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kubernetes, kops

I'm new to AWS and I'm trying to deploy Kubernetes for some tutorial purposes using `kops`.
For that, I'm using a trial AWS account and I started following [this practical guide](https://ramhiser.com/post/2018-05-20-setting-up-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-aws-in-5-minutes/) to do it but I have an issue with this command :

```
kops create cluster --node-count=2 --node-size=t2.medium --zones=us-east-1a
```

which gives me the following error :

```
I0119 16:14:49.647701   13949 create_cluster.go:517] Inferred --cloud=aws from zone "eu-west-3a"

error populating configuration: error querying for valid AZs in "eu-west-3" - verify your AWS credentials.  Error: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
    status code: 403, request id: a1f6e99f-76d6-4c3f-95bb-416cc2d67f2e
```

I wonder if it's not related to some limited access due to my trial AWS account !

Comment: Can you confirm that AWS S3 bucket, Default region name and zone have set the same zone?

Comment: @PjoterS my S3 bucket is on USA est, North Virginia

Answer (score 0):

Looks like AWS credentials are not properly setup, verify them with e.g.:

```
$ aws sts get-caller-identity 
{
    "Account": "<number>", 
    "UserId": "AI...", 
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::<number>:user/<user>"
}
```

Comment: this is what it returns : `{
    "Account": "XXXXXXXX9734", 
    "UserId": "AIDAVINRIHWLXXXXXXXX", 
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX9734:user/s3-full-access-user"
}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I don't have enough rights to do it since my user had only `AmazonS3FullAccess`. 

Now I added :

```
AmazonEC2FullAccess
AmazonRoute53FullAccess
IAMFullAccess
AmazonVPCFullAccess
```